# How to create facebook SignIn & google SignIn button as a floating action button in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on android project.In my project, There are two SignIn buttons in my application (facebook,Google).It works properly.So i want to make that Signin buttons as a floating buttons.So how we can do that? I tried it and i also searched on google. But i didn't get any proper solution for it.. So Give me a solution..and 
Can we customize Normal Signin button as a floatingButton?

Comment: Using a FAB in this manner isnt really following the design guidelines for a FAB. `Only one floating action button is recommended per screen to represent the most common action.` https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use one FAB when you click on it two other ones shows with animation and you can choose one of them, check this [tutorial](https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-floating-action-button-animations.html) for full details.